# yeoman-maven-plugin ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, maven, yeoman

I have recently integrated maven yeoman plugin with my app. I followed https://github.com/trecloux/yeoman-maven-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md  My angular version is **v1.2.3** . When I  run the **mvn clean install** command, I get the following error .

```
grunt-contrib-imagemin@0.3.0 node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin
Γö£ΓöÇΓöÇ filesize@1.10.0
Γö£ΓöÇΓöÇ chalk@0.2.1 (ansi-styles@0.2.0, has-color@0.1.4)
Γö£ΓöÇΓöÇ optipng-bin@0.3.1 (bin-wrapper@0.1.9)
Γö£ΓöÇΓöÇ gifsicle@0.1.4 (bin-wrapper@0.1.9)
Γö£ΓöÇΓöÇ pngquant-bin@0.1.6 (bin-wrapper@0.1.9)
ΓööΓöÇΓöÇ jpegtran-bin@0.2.3 (bin-wrapper@0.1.9)
[INFO] --------------------------------------
[INFO]          BOWER INSTALL --NO-COLOR
[INFO] --------------------------------------
bower angular-sanitize#~1.2.0   cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sa
nitize.git#1.2.7
bower angular-sanitize#~1.2.0 validate 1.2.7 against git://github.com/angular/bo
wer-angular-sanitize.git#~1.2.0
bower angular-sanitize#~1.2.0      new version for git://github.com/angular/bowe
r-angular-sanitize.git#~1.2.0
bower angular-sanitize#~1.2.0  resolve git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sa
nitize.git#~1.2.0
bower angular-sanitize#~1.2.0 download https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-
sanitize/archive/v1.2.15-build.2365+sha.d07101d.tar.gz
bower angular-sanitize#~1.2.0  extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular-sanitize#~1.2.0 resolved git://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sa
nitize.git#1.2.15-build.2365+sha.d07101d
bower angular#1.2.15-build.2365+sha.d07101d       not-cached git://github.com/an
gular/bower-angular.git#1.2.15-build.2365+sha.d07101d
bower angular#1.2.15-build.2365+sha.d07101d          resolve git://github.com/an
gular/bower-angular.git#1.2.15-build.2365+sha.d07101d
bower angular#1.2.15-build.2365+sha.d07101d         download https://github.com/
angular/bower-angular/archive/v1.2.15-build.2365+sha.d07101d.tar.gz
bower angular#1.2.15-build.2365+sha.d07101d          extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular#1.2.15-build.2365+sha.d07101d         resolved git://github.com/an
gular/bower-angular.git#1.2.15-build.2365+sha.d07101d
bower angular#1.2.7                                   cached git://github.com/an
gular/bower-angular.git#1.2.7
bower angular#1.2.7                                 validate 1.2.7 against git:/
/github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.7
bower angular#~1.2.0                                  cached git://github.com/an
gular/bower-angular.git#1.2.14
bower angular#~1.2.0                                validate 1.2.14 against git:
//github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.2.0
bower angular#~1.2.0                                     new version for git://g
ithub.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.2.0
bower angular#~1.2.0                                 resolve git://github.com/an
gular/bower-angular.git#~1.2.0
bower angular#~1.2.0                                download https://github.com/
angular/bower-angular/archive/v1.2.15-build.2365+sha.d07101d.tar.gz
bower angular#~1.2.0                                 extract archive.tar.gz
bower angular#~1.2.0                                resolved git://github.com/an
gular/bower-angular.git#1.2.15-build.2365+sha.d07101d
bower                                              **ECONFLICT Unable to find suit
able version for angular**
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:44.452s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Mar 05 19:37:34 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/73M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.trecloux:yeoman-maven-plugin:0.1:build
 (default) on project C****_UI: Error during : cmd /c bower install --no-color:
 Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal c
om.github.trecloux:yeoman-maven-plugin:0.1:build (default) on project C****_UI:
 Error during : cmd /c bower install --no-color
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBu
ild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error during : cmd /c
 bower install --no-color
        at com.axonactive.yeoman.YeomanMojo.executeCommand(YeomanMojo.java:68)
        at com.axonactive.yeoman.YeomanMojo.bowerInstall(YeomanMojo.java:47)
        at com.axonactive.yeoman.YeomanMojo.execute(YeomanMojo.java:39)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:209)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an erro
r: 1 (Exit value: 1)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecut
or.java:377)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:
160)
        at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:
147)
        at com.axonactive.yeoman.YeomanMojo.executeCommand(YeomanMojo.java:66)
        ... 23 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
```

I tried updating my angular version and it worked fine with  **v1.2.15-build.2365+sha.d07101d** . But I don't want to update my angular version at this moment. Is there something that I have missed ?

```
{
  "name": "c****",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.2.3",
    "json3": "~3.2.4",
    "es5-shim": "~2.1.0",
    "jquery": "~1.10.2",
    "sass-bootstrap": "~3.0.0",
    "angular-resource": "~1.2.3",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.2.3",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.2.3",
    "angular-route": "~1.2.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.2.3",
    "angular-scenario": "~1.2.3"
  }
}



D:\Repo\yo>bower install
bower not-cached    git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.15-build.2389
+sha.c5f2f58
bower resolve       git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.15-build.2389
+sha.c5f2f58
bower cached        git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.14
bower validate      1.2.14 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1
.2.4
bower download      https://github.com/angular/bower-angular/archive/v1.2.15-bui
ld.2389+sha.c5f2f58.tar.gz
bower new           version for git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.2.
4
bower resolve       git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.2.4
bower download      https://github.com/angular/bower-angular/archive/v1.2.15-bui
ld.2391+sha.53ec5e1.tar.gz
bower extract       angular#~1.2.4 archive.tar.gz
bower resolved      git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.15-build.2391
+sha.53ec5e1
bower extract       angular#1.2.15-build.2389+sha.c5f2f58 archive.tar.gz
bower resolved      git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.15-build.2389
+sha.c5f2f58
bower install       angular#1.2.15-build.2389+sha.c5f2f58
```

My bower version is 1.2.7. bower install works fine, I have even installed underscore using install cmd.

Comment: Could you provide your bower.json file ? Can you confirm that the "boer install"command fails too ?

Comment: {
  "name": "c****",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.2.3",
    "json3": "~3.2.4",
    "es5-shim": "~2.1.0",
    "jquery": "~1.10.2",
    "sass-bootstrap": "~3.0.0",
    "angular-resource": "~1.2.3",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.2.3",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.2.3",
    "angular-route": "~1.2.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.2.3",
    "angular-scenario": "~1.2.3"
  }
}

Comment: @thomas Can you tell what exactly do I need to check in "bower install"

Comment: In a shell and from your bower.json folder, type "bower install".
Can you also provide me your bower version ?

Comment: I also find that all my angular components get updated whenever I run mvn clean install